# DNS Issue: Having the old host serve email with a new host for the website

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, mediatemple

I redesign the local red cross website. They wanted to retain their email service with their current host.

Their existing web host has created a DNS record that points to my MediaTemple server.

pvredcross.org   A   205.186.157.246
www.pvredcross.org A   205.186.157.246

I added the domain pvredcross.org to my account at MediaTemple. I also created the necessary domain in Plesk for pvredcross.org

When I ping pvredcross.org it successfully pings my MT server.

BUT when I try and access it via the web it doesn't find the webpage.

Is there any special DNS settings I should be using on my end?

The old web host retains the DNS control over the domain but just points to my MT server for the website.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is megavision.com managing the DNS for you?

Because it looks like the DNS records are wrong (according to what you indicated in your post)
http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=express&host=pvredcross.org

The A records you are mentioning are simply missing...

Comment: yep they are the old web host. did they not set it up correctly? they are a windows host so maybe they don't know how to setup A records.

Comment: i wonder how they have it setup? From the link you posted above it doesn't even show and A records.... how the heck is www.pvredcross.org even pinging my server? thanks alex